# Add XElement in another XElement in specific location

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

My XML:

```
<Bank>
    <Customer id="0">
        <Accounts>
            <Account id="0" />
            <Account id="1" />
        </Accounts>
    </Customer>
    <Customer id="2">
        <Accounts>
            <Account id="0" />
        </Accounts>
    </Customer>
</Bank>
```

i want to add  new account element before customer id=2.
i have this xml in xelement and i want to add other xelement to the first. how can do that?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want that ?  Asking this because the order of xml element should not cause any issue in serialization or deserialization.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a new `Custom` element, or a new `Account` element (or both)?

Comment: no i want to add  <Customer id="1">
        <Accounts>
            <Account id="0" />
        </Accounts>
    </Customer>    before  <Customer id="2">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linq-to-xml makes this easy:

```
// Parse our XML document to an XDocument
var xml = @"<Bank>
    <Customer id=""0"">
        <Accounts>
            <Account id=""0"" />
            <Account id=""1"" />
        </Accounts>
    </Customer>
    <Customer id=""2"">
        <Accounts>
            <Account id=""0"" />
        </Accounts>
    </Customer>
</Bank>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

// Create our new Customer to add
var newCustomer = new XElement("Customer",
    new XAttribute("id", "1"),
    new XElement("Accounts",
        new XElement("Account", new XAttribute("id", "0"))
    )
);

// Find the customer with id="2"
var customer2 = doc.Root.Elements("Customer").First(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "2");
// Add the new customer before the customer with id="2"
customer2.AddBeforeSelf(newCustomer);
```

Comment: is it necessary to use the doc=Xdocument.parse(xml)? because i used a XElement    XElement myxElement = new XElement();
MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream();
                    myxElement.Save(myStream);    isn't possible to update this myxElement ?

Comment: @Ammar.Dev You can get the `XDocument` however you like. I added it to my answer so you can just run it. In the code you just posted, that's you *saving* an XElement to a stream, not *loading* it from somewhere

Comment: @ canton7 no i mean i loaded the xdocument and i want to save that as XElement but before save that i want to add to this XElement an Other XElement. and that's this title of my post. i mean how to add a new XElement to an Exist XElement ?

Comment: @Ammar.Dev So you've already got the code to create `doc`? If so, skip the first two lines in my answer, and start directly at the bit which creates `newCustomer`

Comment: @ canton7 and what about doc.Root ? i don't know my doc because i just have XElement?

Comment: @Ammar.Dev If you've got an `XElement` called `element`, then do `element.Elements("Customer")...` (i.e. just remove `.Root`). I would recommend parsing your XML document to an `XDocument` rather than an `XElement` though, as `XDocument` has additional features which relate specifically to documents.

Comment: @ canton7 is it possible to parse an XElement to Xdocument ?if is it possible it will be great  and i can fix that

Comment: No. Like I said, `XDocument` contains things which `XElement` doesn't. Where you currently create your root `XElement`,  just change that to instead create an `XDocument`. Regardless, the code in my answer will work if you just have an `XElement`: just remove `.Root`, as I said before